# Creating dynamic datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a problem when trying to create a jQuery datapicker dynamicaly.
Here is the code:

```
var group = document.createElement("div");
group.setAttribute("id", "group_" + control.id);
$("#group_" + control.id).addClass("input-group");
parent.append(group);

var input = document.createElement("input");        
input.setAttribute("id", control.id);
input.setAttribute("type", "text");


$("#" + control.id).datepicker();
$("#group_" + control.id).append(input);
```

I am trying to fire this logic on custom event. All html elements created dynamically.
When I am trying to click on dynamic created element date menu not appearing.

All required js/css files loaded to this page.

Comment: Could you also post any HTML you have? Are you using jQueryUI datepicker?

Comment: Yes, this is jQuery datepicker.

Comment: I'm sorry but there are a number of jQuery datepickers (jQueryUI includes one of them). I just want to make sure you have included the requiered JS files. Can you put together a simple jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is fiddler trace: 
 
 bootstrap.css
    Site.css
    modernizr-2.7.1.js 
    jquery-1.6.4.js 
    jquery-2.1.0.js 
    jquery-ui-1.10.4.js
    jquery-ui.css 
    jquery.ui.button.css 
    jquery.ui.tooltip.css 
    jquery.delicious-button-1.0.min.js 
    bootstrap.min.js 
    WebForms.js 
   WebUIValidation.js 
    MenuStandards.js
    GridView.js 
   DetailsView.js
    TreeView.js
    WebParts.js